# How to do migration from Magento 2 EE to Magento 2 CE?

Tags: magento2.3, migration, magento2-migration-tool

How to do migration from Magento 2 EE to Magento 2 CE ? Is there any way to do that ?

Can I do that ? If yes please let me now how to do that ? Which process I have to follow ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to do it by yourself**

```
 1. Backup your database and source code.
 2. Install Magento 2 CE version.
 3. Copy entire your EE database to the installed Magento 2 CE store (override existing tables).
 4. Remove `row_id` column from all these tables: `catalog_product_entity_*` and `catalog_category_entity_*`
 5. Turn on debug mode in Magento CE, debug other issues to make sure everything works properly.
```

**If you are looking forward to hiring a migration service or a developer**

Try this [Mgaento to Magento migration service](https://next-cart.com/product/magento-to-magento/). They will do everything as your needs.

Comment: Are we still need of enterprise's attribute or table ?

Comment: It depends on you. You will need them to preserve the relationship between Products and Attributes, I recommend you to keep EE tables.

As I know, EEdb is quite similar to CEdb, the major difference is the `row_id` reference key in category and product tables. You will need to create a mapping table for `row_id` and `entity_id` unless they are the same at all.

Answer (score 0):

we know magento migration process could be a hectic task, for those who are not much aware and knowledgeable from a technical aspect, but there is many companies providing magento migration service, so that anyone can migrate from magento 1 to magento 2 easily, you can avail [magento migration service](https://cedcommerce.com/magento-services/magento-1-to-magento-2-migration?utm_source=stackexchange&utm_medium=sonker) from CedCommerce. they will provide you dedicated developers and 24/7 support.